# Sort on nested field using MongoDB

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I have data stored in a collection like so:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
    "content" : [
        ["a","b",7],
        ["a","b",19],
        ["c","c",3],
        ["d","a",5]
    ]
}
```

I want to fetch one record from the collection (which is easy enough) but I want to return that data sorted by the content using the 3rd column of each array. Meaning, I'd like to get back the record (shown above) but have content be sorted such that:

```
    "content" : [
        ["c","c",3],
        ["d","a",5],
        ["a","b",7],
        ["a","b",19]
    ]
```

Is that possible or do I just need to fetch the item and then sort it server-side?

note: I'm using the Ruby mongo driver

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
hash = {
    "_id" => "id",
    "content" => [
        ["a","b",7],
        ["a","b",19],
        ["c","c",3],
        ["d","a",5]
    ]
}
hash["content"].sort!{|a,b| a.last <=> b.last}
p hash # => {"_id"=>"1", "content"=>[["c", "c", 3], ["d", "a", 5], ["a", "b", 7], ["a", "b", 19]]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've realized also that having this nested array(s) is more of a pain than just having an array of objects, so I'm changing to that for my situation. There is some discussion of supporting nested positional operators though: http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch and sort client-side. MongoDB doesn't sort nested objects. If you want MongoDB to sort it, you'll have to break the "content" data out into its own collection.